# yum command not working using Red Hat

Tags: java, redhat

I want to install java using yum command (Red Hat Enterprise Linux Version 5) but exception arises..

```
$ yum install java-1.6.0-openjdk
Loading "rhnplugin" plugin
Loading "security" plugin
Loading "installonlyn" plugin
**This system is not registered with RHN.**
RHN support will be disabled.
```

plz help i m new for linux..

Comment: your error is simmilar to one described in this link: http://flashdba.com/2012/10/08/this-system-is-not-registered-with-uln-rhn/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run this from your command prompt to register your server:

```
rhn_register
```

If your new to linux I'm going to suggest the nixCraft website as one (of many) excellent resources to *nix tutorials and questions.

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/rhel-centos-fedora-linux-yum-command-howto/